# RDP to Windows 7 in Hyper-V with RemoteFX?

Tags: hyper-v, rdp, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 VM running on a Hyper-V server. I connect to this VM from another machine (also running Win7).

Will my remote connection be able to benefit from the new [RemoteFX](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/rds-remotefx.aspx) features coming in in the next service pack for Win7/Server2008R2, or is this only for terminal service-type configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this paragraph:

> For virtual desktops deployed on top
>   of the Hyper-V virtualization platform
>   in Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1,
>   graphics hardware-assisted rendering
>   of the screen content on the VDI host
>   will ensure that even the most
>   advanced applications today and
>   tomorrow will “just work”.

The answer to your question is: yes, but I'm guessing there will be caveats (there always are).

You can find their [hardware considerations here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817602%28WS.10%29.aspx). The Hyper-V server will require a DirectX 10 compatible graphics card (Which could be a pain because 2008 R2 has a few known issues with the Hyper-V role and high-end graphics cards. We'll see if they've been fixed in SP1). Looks like you're going to need a LOT of video ram if you want multiple sessions at anything but 1024x768, and if you want to do live migration you'll need identical GPUs.

Comment: The issues with Hyper-V and high end video cards appear to have been fixed in SP1. I didn't see anything in the release notes but I'm not having any issues with my setup (Nvidia Quadro 880).

Comment: One caveat is you seem to need Remote Desktop Services licenses for the host in order to turn on the RemoteFX Virtualization Host.

Comment: I amend my last statement - there is a different licensing model and the RD Virtualization Host can be configured to get licenses independently of the RD Session Host: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2010/12/15/configuring-remote-desktop-licensing-settings-on-a-remote-desktop-virtualization-host-server.aspx